# Wildcard in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

How do I convert the following formula to do wildcard for "Florida"?

```
=Sumproduct((Sheet1!B:B="Florida"),Sheet1!A:A)
```

Ideally, I like the formula to do this:

```
=Sumproduct((Sheet1!B:B="*Florida*"),Sheet1!A:A)
```

but the wildcard doesn't work in this formula!

Answer (score 1):

May not answer your question but might be of use:

```
=sumif(Sheet1!B:B,"*Florida*",Sheet1!A:A)
```